# Using || in javascript switches

Tags: javascript

Is this code possible?

```
switch (rule)
{
   case 'email' || 'valid_email':
    valid = this.validate_email(field);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close, but this will work:

```
switch (rule)
{
  case 'email':
  case 'valid_email':
    valid = this.validate_email(field);
    break;
}
```

The reason why it works is that without a `break;`, execution continues within the `switch` block.

Answer (score 15):

No, it is not possible, Switch statements doesn't do arithmetic calculus.

However, you can use case chaining or a bunch of if's:

```
switch (rule)
{
   case 'email':
   case 'valid_email':
    valid = this.validate_email(field);
    break;
}
```

Comment: if chasing brevity, this one-liner would work too: case 'email': case 'valid_email':